# Java Mutable and Immutable concepts

Tags: java, immutability, mutable

Can we create an Immutable object, that contains a mutable object? Is is possible? 
please make me more clear about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can.

Take for example the code from `java.lang.String`:

```
/** The value is used for character storage. **/
private final char value[];
```

Obviously arrays are mutable because we can easily change their content like this:

```
value[0] = '&';
```

However `String` is still immutable. That is, once created, its contents will never change. How does that happen?

Because even though `value` is mutable, there's no "regular" way for the user of `String` to modify it:

1. `value` is declared `private final`. And `String` itself is `final`, meaning no subclass.
2. There's no setter methods. Nor any methods that modifies `value`.
3. We can create a string from a char array, but the char array is copied inside the constructor, so modifying the original array would have no effect to the newly created string.
4. The `value` field could also be shared by multiple `String` instances, but as long as it's not leaked, it's safe.
5. We can convert a string back to a char array, but again, its a copy.

So the answer is yes, if we follow a [design strategy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html) carefully.

Answer (score 1):

In Java (and as far as I know all other mainstream languages with a `const` / `final` / `readyonly` / `val` etc keyword) an "immutable" object can contain references to mutable objects.  For a deeper dive into immutability see [this paper](http://homepages.mcs.vuw.ac.nz/~alex/files/PotaninOstlundZibinErnstImmutability2013.pdf) - the quick takeaway is that there are unofficial Java extensions that allow you to specify that e.g. an immutable object can only contain references to immutable objects, e.g. [Javari](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~mernst/pubs/ref-immutability-oopsla2005.pdf) or [Joe3](https://people.dsv.su.se/~tobias/iwaco.pdf) or [OIGJ](http://homepages.mcs.vuw.ac.nz/~alex/files/ZibinPotaninLiAliErnstOOPSLA2010.pdf)

Comment: Immutable objects can be composed (though not via aggregation) of mutable objects (`char[]` is mutable in `String`) as long as the object doesn't mutate itself in ways the modifies the state of the immutable object composed of it. Any attempts to modify such state should spawn a new object (such as `toLowercase()` and `toCharArray()`). Otherwise, the object will not be naturally thread safe, which is a huge violation of immutable characteristics. If the immutable object references a mutable object, there must be no outside references to that object.

Comment: The question was whether it was **possible** for an "immutable" object to reference a mutable object; however I entirely agree that this is inadvisable even though it is possible.

Comment: Using final/readonly doesn't make the object itself immutable, it just makes it a constant reference.

Comment: @EJoshuaS The literature is unfortunately wildly inconsistent when it comes to defining an "immutable object," but often the term only refers to "shallow" immutability (all of the object's fields are `final` but these references may point to mutable objects) owing to the fact that "deep" immutability usually can't be defined at the programming language level but instead must be defined using design patterns or static analysis tools etc.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot Fair enough. By that definition, then, a "shallow immutable" object can contain constant references to mutable objects and a "deep immutable" object can only contain constant references to constant objects. I think that that could be a reasonable answer in this case, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) covers this pretty well: "*In some cases, an object is considered immutable even if some internally used attributes change **but the object's state appears to be unchanging from an external point of view***". Immutable types *can* be composed of mutable objects, but only under strict conditions. I only made the comment to prevent confusion: if the immutable type is shallow, special attention is needed towards corner-case restrictions to ensure immutability

Answer (score 0):

Objects in Java never really *contain* other objects--not like in C or in some other programming languages.  Even the so-called "container" classes really just contain *references* to other objects.

An immutable object can refer to *any* other objects, mutable or immutable.

You can't change which other objects an immutable object refers to, but you can change the other objects if they are mutable.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: This depends somewhat on what you mean by "immutable." As another person pointed out, sometimes "immutable" is defined as a form of "shallow" immutability - i.e. constant references to mutable objects are allowed. I'm not fond of this definition myself. Some people might disagree with me here (and hopefully no one will downvote b/c of a difference of opinion), I think it's much clearer to define "immutability" as "having no mutable state of any kind."

Under this definition, the answer to your question is **no* because if it refers to mutable objects that gives it mutable state, which would make the object itself mutable.

I think it's important at this point to distinguish between a constant *reference* or *pointer* and an immutable *object*. For example, the following code is a constant reference to a constant object:

```
private final string abc = "John";
```

Note that you can't modify the state of "abc" (i.e. that particular string will *always* be "John" - you can't change it to "Johnny" later, you'd need to create a new string. Also, you can't replace "John" with a new string (i.e. the variable "abc" itself will always refer to that string).

The following code is a mutable reference to an immutable object:

```
public string abc = "John";
```

(By the way, I do realize you should use a property here instead).

If you were to later do:

```
abc = "Johnny";
```

you'd be allowed to do that. In this case, you're changing the object that the variable "abc" is referring to, *not* the original string. The string "John" will *always* have that value as long as it exists.

However, consider the following object:

```
public class Defg
{
    public int Count;

    public Defg(int Count)
    {
       this.Count = Count;
    }
}
```

Clearly, this is a mutable class (because you can change the value of "Count").

You can do the following:

```
// Mutable reference to a mutable object. Note: "Count: 1" is a bit of C# syntax that just means that the "Count" parameter is set to 1. It's not strictly necessary here, I just added it for clarity.
public Defg Mutable = new Defg(Count: 1);

// Constant reference to a mutable object
public final Defg ConstReference = new Defg(Count: 1);
```

Note that the following is all perfectly valid:

```
Mutable = new Defg(Count: 10);
Mutable.Count = 4;
ConstReference.Count = 3;
```

However, you *cannot* do the following:

```
ConstReference = new Defg(Count: 3);
```

Note, in particular, that Defg *can't possibly* be an immutable object because you can change its state.

To summarize:
a) It's perfectly possible to have either a mutable reference to a constant object or a constant reference to a mutable object - the mutability of the *reference to* the object has nothing to do with whether the object itself is mutable and *vice versa*.
b) Whether an object that refers to mutable objects can still be considered immutable depends on your definition of "immutable." In my opinion it can't because referring to a mutable object gives it mutable state; it would be confusing/misleading at best to describe that as immutable.

Comment: This answer is a bit confusing for people who have little knowledge of C#, e.g. me.

Comment: @LukeLee Fair enough, I'll edit to use more familiar syntax.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it's possible. But access modifier of variable     which refers to mutable object must be final.

Comment: "final" isn't an access modifier.